# Error con PhpUnit en Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Tengo una implementacion de Laravel 5.8 usando WAMP, estoy tratando de estudiar PHPUNIT pero cuando tratado de ejecutar las pruebas siempre recibo este mensaje:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner::getTest() must 
be of the type string, array given, called in  
C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php on line 120 and 
defined in C:\
wamp\www\covermanagertest\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:86
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php(120): 
PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner->getTest('C:\\wamp\\www\\cov...', Array)
#1 C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php(96): 
PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run(Array, true)
#2 C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit(61): 
PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
#3 {main}

Next PHPUnit\TextUI\RuntimeException: Argument 2 passed to PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner::getTest() 
must be of the type string, array given, called in 
C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php on line 120 in 
C:\Users\J
o in C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php on line 98
```

Como podran ver, estoy trabajando con Windows, espero que alguien haya tenido el mismo problema y pueda orientarme. Gracias.

/*EDITADO*/

Aqui les dejo la configuracion del phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false">
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Unit">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
    </testsuite>

    <testsuite name="Feature">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
<php>
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
    <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
    <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
</php>
```

Otra cosa que he descubierto es que si coloco la ruta absoluta puedo ejecutar test unitarios, pero esto para mi no tiene sentido:

```
C:\wamp\www\laravelunit\vendor\bin>phpunit 
c:\wamp\www\laravelunit\tests\Unit\ExampleTest.php
PHPUnit 7.5.20 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

 .                                                                   1 / 1 
(100%)

Time: 408 ms, Memory: 12.00 MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)

C:\wamp\www\laravelunit\vendor\bin>
```

Comment: que version de php estas usando? en la linea 98 del Comand.php (del vendor) esta la definición de unos parametros de configuración. Me da a entender que hay algo mal configurado en el phpunit.xml de tu proyecto. Puedes publicarlo?

Comment: Hola lo he puesto

Comment: Sin embargo quiero decir algo, la unica manera que logre (por ahora) que esto funcionara era creando test unitarios colocando las rutas absolutas (no relativas) y de esa manera si funciona, sigo diciendo que no tiene sentido.

Comment: lo ultimo suena a que no tienes configurado el psr4 del entorno dev, en tu composer.json. Deberias tener algo como: "autoload-dev": {"tests": "tests/"} para indicar asi la correspondencia de namespace-directorio de los tests...

Comment: Si lo tengo:   "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }